# How to parse a dynamic Json String using the Json Api

Tags: json, vb.net

Im currently trying to parse this String into my program with the API from 
 http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm

```
{
"193461232": [
    {
        "name": "Master Yi's Pyromancers",
        "tier": "GOLD",
        "queue": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
        "entries": [
            {
                "playerOrTeamId": "193461232",
                "playerOrTeamName": "wamborambo",
                "division": "V",
                "leaguePoints": 58,
                "wins": 109,
                "losses": 104,
                "isHotStreak": false,
                "isVeteran": false,
                "isFreshBlood": false,
                "isInactive": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Elise's Masterminds",
        "tier": "BRONZE",
        "queue": "RANKED_TEAM_3x3",
        "entries": [
            {
                "playerOrTeamId": "TEAM-4f44680-9f2b-11e4-8954-c81f66db8bc5",
                "playerOrTeamName": "KidsClub",
                "division": "IV",
                "leaguePoints": 63,
                "wins": 6,
                "losses": 8,
                "isHotStreak": false,
                "isVeteran": false,
                "isFreshBlood": false,
                "isInactive": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Elise's Horde",
        "tier": "BRONZE",
        "queue": "RANKED_TEAM_5x5",
        "entries": [
            {
                "playerOrTeamId": "TEAM-4f457640-9f2b-11e4-8954-c81f66db8bc5",
                "playerOrTeamName": "KidsClub",
                "division": "I",
                "leaguePoints": 28,
                "wins": 6,
                "losses": 4,
                "isHotStreak": false,
                "isVeteran": false,
                "isFreshBlood": false,
                "isInactive": false
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

They Problem is the String is dynamic.
I have to get "193461232" first before i can use the String.
I have also the problem because name, queue, entries are arrays
And I practiced with Simple Jsons first but this one is really hard for me.

Sorry my english is not really good but I hope you can still understand my Problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"193461232" is probably something related to the request, in other words I dont think it is random.  It may even be your playerId - the value *also* appears as the `playerOrTeamId` for the first group (and the related `playerOrTeamName` is similar to yours here).  That said, I do not know how that Id relates to the other two items returned.  Even if you don't know it,  you can get it.

Once you do, unless you only need one or two things from the json, you need some classes to deserialize to:

```
Public Class EntryItem
    Public Property playerOrTeamId As String
    Public Property playerOrTeamName As String
    Public Property division As String
    Public Property leaguePoints As Integer
    Public Property wins As Integer
    Public Property losses As Integer
    Public Property isHotStreak As Boolean
    Public Property isVeteran As Boolean
    Public Property isFreshBlood As Boolean
    Public Property isInactive As Boolean
End Class

Public Class Entry
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property tier As String
    Public Property queue As String
    Public Property entries As List(Of EntryItem)
End Class
```

With those, its pretty simple:

```
Dim jstr = from whereever

Dim jobj = JObject.Parse(jstr)

Dim jName = jobj.Properties(0).Name   ' name, ie 193461232
Dim jItems = jobj(jName)              ' related items

Dim items= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Entry())(jItems.ToString)

For n As Int32 = 0 To items.Length - 1
    Console.WriteLine(items(n).name)
Next
```

The output is the team names:

> Master Yi's Pyromancers
>   Elise's Masterminds
>   Elise's Horde

If that is your Id, you can just use `jobj("193461232")` to deserialize.  Of course that may only work for you.  A tool for other players should use `jobj.Properties(0).Name` unless they know their Id too.

---

To access the entry data, just drill into it:

```
myWins = items(0).entries(0).wins
```

Comment: I already solved this problem but im currently working on this array problem.

I dont know how i can get the items  playerOrTeamId or Wins for example. 
but thank you for helping me. Ths helped me a lot for understanding json more ^^

Comment: That is all solved in the answer.  `items(0).entries(0).wins` will be for Master Po.  As shown, there will only be one entry per item, but it is serialized as an array (just in case, I guess).

Comment: Thank you for the help.. i did almost the same but i did a syntax error.
This helped me a lot

Comment: Could you help me again ? :)